# ensureloggedin for both bearer and session node middleware

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

So I have a pretty standart node express setup that uses passport and both the bearer(oauth-client-pass) and the local strategy

I also use connect-ensure-login for the standard 
Here are my routes, the first and second work as they should the third one is the one I cannot get right

```
app.get('/admin', ensureLoggedIn(), index.admin);
app.get('/api/endpoint',passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), index.endpoint);
app.get('/account', ensureLoggedInApi , index.account);
```

where

```
function ensureLoggedInApi(req, res, next) {
if(req.query.access_token)
    passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false });
 else
    ensureLoggedIn();
next();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions return a middleware handler, so you first need to call them (yielding the middleware handler) followed by calling the handler itself:

```
function ensureLoggedInApi(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.access_token) {
    passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false })(req, res, next);
  } else {
    ensureLoggedIn()(req, res, next);
  }
}
```